# How to get the newest contact's picture in outlook 2010?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

Here is the problem:

1. use Attachment.SaveAsFile() to save contact's picture on disk.(successfully)
2. change the contact's picture in outlook manually.
3. repeat step 1, but i get the old picture, not the new one in step 2.

EDIT:
I have know how to save contact's picture on disk.
The problem is that the picture which i get is not the newest one. 
Here is the code:

```
//[Outlook] is short for [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook] 
        Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
        foreach (var item in folder.Items) {
            if (item is Outlook.ContactItem) {
                Outlook.ContactItem contact = null;
                Outlook.Attachments atts = null;
                Outlook.Attachment att = null;
                string path = "";

                contact = item as Outlook.ContactItem;

                if (!contact.HasPicture) { continue; }

                path = @"C:\Temp\" + contact.EntryID + ".jpg";
                atts = contact.Attachments;
                att = atts["ContactPicture.jpg"];

                if(File.Exists(path)){
                    File.Delete(path);
                }

                att.SaveAsFile(@"C:\Temp\" + contact.EntryID + ".jpg");

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(att);
                att = null;
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(atts);
                atts = null;
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(contact);
                contact = null;
            }
        }
```

thanks!

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Make sure the contact is saved

Comment: @Smartis Thanks for your reply. Maybe i didn't describe clear. I don't want  somebody to write the code for me.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yeah,i am sure. I change the contact's picture in outlook manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the resolution on [Contact picture retrieved via PIA doesn't change when updated in Outlook](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5301de1c-e78b-4db0-af43-c2af30498b26/contact-picture-retrieved-via-pia-doesnt-change-when-updated-in-outlook?forum=outlookdev)

I didn't release the `folder.Items`

Here is the modified code：

```
//[Outlook] is short for [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook] 
        Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
        Outlook.Items items = null;
        items = folder.Items;
        foreach (var item in items) {
            if (item is Outlook.ContactItem) {
                Outlook.ContactItem contact = null;
                Outlook.Attachments atts = null;
                Outlook.Attachment att = null;
                string path = "";

                contact = item as Outlook.ContactItem;

                if (!contact.HasPicture) { continue; }

                path = @"C:\Temp\" + contact.EntryID + ".jpg";
                atts = contact.Attachments;
                att = atts["ContactPicture.jpg"];

                if (File.Exists(path)) {
                    File.Delete(path);
                }

                att.SaveAsFile(@"C:\Temp\" + contact.EntryID + ".jpg");

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(att);
                att = null;
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(atts);
                atts = null;
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(contact);
                contact = null;
            }
        }

        if (items != null) {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(items);
            items = null;
        }
```

EDIT:

Problem happened with above code. Sometimes it got the old picture.
I added `GC.Collect();` at the end,then it worked well.

So i tried the following code. But the problem remained.

```
//[Outlook] is short for [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook] 
        Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
        Outlook.Items items = folder.Items;

        foreach (var item in items) {
            if (item is Outlook.ContactItem) {
                Outlook.ContactItem contact = item as Outlook.ContactItem;
                string path = "";
                Outlook.Attachment att = null;

                if (!contact.HasPicture) { continue; }

                path = @"C:\Temp\" + contact.EntryID + ".jpg";
                att = contact.Attachments["ContactPicture.jpg"];

                if (File.Exists(path)) {
                    File.Delete(path);
                }

                att.SaveAsFile(@"C:\Temp\" + contact.EntryID + ".jpg");
            }
        }

        GC.Collect();
```

Finally i use the following code. Release all com objects,then call GC.Collect().

```
//[Outlook] is short for [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook] 
        Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
        Outlook.Items items = folder.Items;

        foreach (var item in items) {
            if (item is Outlook.ContactItem) {
                Outlook.ContactItem contact = null;
                Outlook.Attachments atts = null;
                Outlook.Attachment att = null;
                string path = "";

                contact = item as Outlook.ContactItem;

                if (!contact.HasPicture) { continue; }

                path = @"C:\Temp\" + contact.EntryID + ".jpg";
                atts = contact.Attachments;
                att = atts["ContactPicture.jpg"];

                if (File.Exists(path)) {
                    File.Delete(path);
                }

                att.SaveAsFile(@"C:\Temp\" + contact.EntryID + ".jpg");

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(att);
                att = null;
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(atts);
                atts = null;
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(contact);
                contact = null;
            }
        }

        if (items != null) {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(items);
            items = null;
        }

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
        folder = null;

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlook);
        outlook = null;

        GC.Collect();
```